# google places api invalid request error

Tags: node.js, google-maps, parsing, google-places-api

I have tried to parse google places web api using node.js to get some information about cafes in seoul. It gets the first 20 cafes but when I try to get the next 20 using next_page_token, It says It is an INVALID REQUEST. I found some stack overflow questions which says to try after 0~2 seconds but it doesn't work for me.
The api_key is alright because I got the first 20 successfuly.

```
var search_keyword = "cafe+seoul";
const api_key = "";
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + search_keyword + "&key=" + api_key;

https.get(url, function (res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {

        var response = JSON.parse(body);

        pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {

            if (err) {
                if (conn) {
                    conn.release;
                }
            }
            //INSIDE DB
            // for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //     var place_id = response.results[i].id;
            //     var data = {
            //         place_id: place_id
            //     };
            //     conn.query('INSERT INTO place_id SET ?', data);
            // }


            var next_page_token = response.next_page_token;
            console.log(next_page_token);
            var next_page_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=" + next_page_token + "&key=" + api_key;
            console.log(next_page_url);
            // if (response.next_page_token == null) {
            //     break;
            // }

        })
    });
});
```

It looks like this.

```
 {
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So in these scenarios, it's a good idea to test the Google Places Web Service API stand-alone first. This way you can isolate if something could be going on with the API or if you are incorrectly appending your params.

Trying out your first request with your `search_keyword` will indeed result to the first 20 results. Sample request below. (Just use your own API key)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=cafe%20seoul&key=YOUR_API_KEY

And you will use the `next_page_token` from its response, indeed. But you have to use the same endpoint. I can see you changed yours to `/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/`. It should be something like this instead:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&pagetoken=CoQC8wAAALQDKxtqy8CzlMQlksz3Id8hFE0zsxpMT-4TrNnb5wzppwlBoaKcF0YA9o22o2uZMjZe59IjBBcRi0yUP0lMzGH8CaQLV9pM6apOgvYAJUo8Xn7-a-kvvl5dD5Ju_CNS8NX0oPv9R4IQLQid5j2DA7THb3Mh_WpTVcrtK6eubHW4CDu0Byy69I7-33BSY5RXu94RZQE0n5jpuNIfpTvzpDdXW1vjHyPtBmhu8vEZP8BWy13ja6Wvv_aDne4cTtknq5TFrNpQsfXvVGQeiYA_J7gs7RP6bESpL7NILhghGyr2gIl9El-ziu66HrDq1klGurF4wY-GGNwl8QP1xpbFfL4SEAHx5Zp2ao8drcaQqGyVjMkaFLSChCwXhDXonok6GZvt34XWfA6g

After you get the web service to work stand-alone, you can then check if you are appending the variables properly.

I hope this helps and that you get it working!